# How do Bonsai Trees fit in?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions on Bonsai Trees suitable for the gardening and landscaping exchange?  Would they be considered off-topic?

Are Bonsai Trees within the scope of gardening and landscaping?

Comment: I think they're part of gardening and landscaping, even if said landscaping is on a miniature scale. Just tag the question with `bonsai-trees` or something appropriate, and anyone who really avoids all things bonsai should ignore the tag.

Comment: Just thought I would throw it out there.  I mean from what I understand of Bonsai, its very similar but very different at the same time :D

Comment: Bonsai is a specialised form of gardening, and Bonsai have been and are features of outdoor & indoor gardens

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I do not believe they would be off-topic, at least not anymore off topic than discussion of house plants, window boxes or other non-gardening horticulture questions. I think that pretty much any question having to do with plants is going to be welcome here.

Comment: No question: on-topic in every way.  (Though if the question were something like: "How do I take a picture of a Bonsai?" or something it might be a little bit off-topic. ;-)

Comment: "How do I take a picture..." of anything goes to Photography.SE. :)